# homeomorphism between a compact and a Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

As I was going over my lecture notes I found the following problem which we haven't proof in class
In the example we know $H$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $C$ is a compact topological space and we need to find a homomorphism between them. And my lecture notes say it suffices to find a continuous bijection $f$ from $C$ to $H.$ So I guess the following proposition which we haven't proof must hold
If $H,C$ and $f$ as above then $g=f^{-1}$ is continuous. How can I prove this?
Thank, You

Comment: Show $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets.

Comment: This question gets asked every few weeks. It's sometimes called the closed map lemma.

Comment: I feel that this is not actually a duplicate of the linked question. That question asks how you know that a continuous map from compact to hausdorff is closed. To answer the present question one should also argue that a continuous closed bijection is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard result is Continuous bijection $f$ from a compact space $C$ to Hausdorff  space  $K$ is a Homeomorphism

Enough to show $f$ is a closed map.

let $A$ be a closed set of $C$ which must be  compact so $f(A)$ is also compact and compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

$f^{-1}( f(A))=A$ is closed in $C$ for any closed set $f(A)$ in $K$, so $f^{-1}$ is continuous, hence $f$ is a homeo.

Comment: thank, you for your response

Comment: @user142775 you are welcome