# Show thaf $f$ is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Prove that, if $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space and  $f:X \to Y$ is continuous invertible then $f$ is homeomorphism.

I started like this. Since, $f$ has to be homeomorphism it is equivalent to
the condition $x_{n}\to x \iff f(x_{n}) \to f(x)$.

$(\Rightarrow$) $f$ is continuous, hence from Heine definition we easily get
$x_n \to x \Rightarrow f(x_n) \to f(x)$

$(\Leftarrow)$ We have to show that, $f(x_n)\to f(x) \Rightarrow x_n \to x$.
And that's the right time to use compactness and inverse function, but I have know idea how.

Comment: Hint : you don't know if $(x_n)$ converges but you can take an appropriate subsequence of it.

Comment: This follows from the fact that any bijective continuous function from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. Note that all metric spaces are Hausdorff. See the following question for more information: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776984/homeomorphism-between-a-compact-and-a-hausdorff-space?lq=1

Comment: You didn't specify what $Y$ is.

Comment: @paf $(x_n)$ had better converge, or else $f^{-1}$ is not continuous...

Comment: @paf could tell me something more?

Comment: @AlexG. we haven't defined what Hausdorff space is which is why I can't use it

Comment: @janusz Look up the definition of Hausdorff space. You can use that property regardless of whether your class has defined the word Hausdorff yet. Just don't use the word Hausdorff yourself in your work.

Comment: If Y is not Hausdorff the proposition is false. For example if X is a 2-element metric space and Y is a 2-element space with the coarse (anti-discrete) topology, and f is a bijection. For the proposition to be true it is sufficient that X be compact Hausdorff and Y be Hausdorff. The Q seems, to me, to assume that Y is a metric space.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** : Since $X$ is compact, $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{\varphi(n)})$. Suppose its limit $y$ is different from $x$ and use continuity and injectivity of $f$ to derive a contradiction about the sequence $(f(x_{\varphi(n)}))$. (Implicitly, this uses Hausdorff property mentioned by @Alex G. in his comments.)